# Getting the API request error even though no APIs are consumed

Tags: api, spring15

I just registered a new org and we are making web service calls out "Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: TotalRequests Limit exceeded. faultcode=sf:REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED faultactor=".

However, the APIs consumed in the last 24 hours is zero. Please see the screenshot.

How to fix this error?
[image]

Comment: have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's the service you are *calling* that is returning the error, not Salesforce itself.  Have you checked the logs on the service side, or tried calling it with some other tool (e.g. SoapUI) to see if you can call the service successfully before trying it via Apex?